# Lumen time stamp Trailing Data and Data Missing errors

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, lumen, php-carbon

I have the same project on AWS EBS and my local Apache. I defined the $dateFormat in my User Model like this,

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

The local server works well, but AWS says,

```
Trailing data
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-14 04:34:08.000') in Model.php line 2991
```

So I changed $dateFormat to this,

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
```

Then the local server will show,

```
Data missing
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2017-09-14 04:34:08') in Model.php line 2991
```

I thought it's the mismatch between the format in the database with the format defined in the Models, but with these different behaviours, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this case is of **Too much data**

If your date string is "longer" than the format string like in this case:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-14 04:34:08.000');
```

Carbon will throw:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Trailing data

Because here you have specified the datetime format with seconds but in your string you are passing the milliseconds value too 08.000 that's why carbon is throwing this error of `Trailing data`

if you don't need millsecond then simply use this

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-14 04:34:08');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's in two different environments, AWS and my local server. If I use the default setting, the behaviour is different. That's why I'm confused as all the other things except the date format are identical.

Comment: If I use the default setting, my local machine will be fine, but AWS will alert the trailing data error which caused by the milliseconds. I don't know if it's related to the system time format...

Comment: if you are comfortable then you can edit and format the date string as specified in my answers so post

Comment: have you tired this?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I need to change the date format every time before I deploy to AWS. That's a bit annoying, however, I still don't know why it happens...

Comment: hey yeah do you need milliseconds too?

Comment: Actually, I don't care much about the format. Anyway, do you know where does the second parameter come from? (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-14 04:34:08.000') ) Is it from the back-end system time, database system time, or the time stored in the database?

Comment: from server ie., from backend there is no interference of db in that and if you don't care about milliseconds then try the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mate. That sort of explained the errors, but I'm still confused about the format of this second parameter. In this case, it's the time that row in the database was created, so I thought it's the format which stored in the database, but why it's related to the server time format?

Comment: because it's the server that is hosting not the database so it should be related to machine time (server time) simply use this I think you won't get the error `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-14 04:34:08')`

Comment: you are getting this error because you are specifying the default format (with seconds) but you are passing the string with milliseconds.

Comment: Not yet. Need to fix some minor bugs first. Thank for your help mate.

Comment: ok if it fix your issue then please accept that answer thanks it was pleasure to help you :)